# higher page reclaims when using munmap

Tags: c, mmap

On Mac my use of munmap results in seeing higher page reclaims.

The return value of my munmap is 0, which indicates that the requested pages where successfully unmapped.

Why do I see higher page reclaims when I test programs using memory I have mapped and unmapped in this way?

Is there a way to debug munmap and see if my calls to that function aren't doing anything to the mapped memory that is passed to it.

I used "/usr/bin/time -l" to see the amount of page reclaims I get from running my program. Whenever I use munmap my page reclaims get higher then when I don't.

```
int           main(void)          
{                                                           
        int i = 0; char *addr;
        while (i < 1024)
        {
            addr = mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
            addr[0] = 23;
            if (!munmap(addr, getpagesize()))
                print("Success\n");
            i++;
        }


        return (NULL);                                      
}
```

on allocation

when I call munmap:

- I pass it the same pointer it gave me.
- I check the return value and check if it is 0 <-- this is what I get most of the time.

I made a test program where I call mmap 1024 times and munmap that number of times too.

When I don't call munmap the reclaimed pages are within the region of 1478 and the value is the same when I call munmap.

How can I check if my use of that memory is correct?

Comment: What is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: how can you have only 730 page faults if you mmap *and* modify 1024 pages?

Comment: Sorry about that. It was 730 with my previous code. I was actually doing more with the page to make my own malloc.
In the code I put up there now I didn't update that paragraph.

Comment: So, we've got a piece of code that does not highlight the actual problem which is with some *other* code?

Comment: You get  ~same value without and with unmap? Also you get 0 *most of the time from munmap* - what does this mean? You ought to get 0 from munmap **every single time** unless you're not randomly shooting at memory addresses munmapping here and there...

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake.
The problem is in that code though.
I called mmap 1024 times and munmap for each one.
I wanted to know why I see so many page reclaims even when I use munmap.

Comment: Ah. OK, that is easy to answer.

Comment: Yes. The value is the same.

Comment: I get 0 on all munmap requests. I counted the number of lines printed by my program and it was 1024 lines.
Shouldn't calling munmap reduce the amount of times the kernel has to reclaim those pages since they've already been given back to the system?

Comment: Try compiling the same code, preceding it with `dtruss` (will need root privileges). Like `dtruss gcc your_file.c` You may get some useful information which helps you to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing to remember about `mmap` is that the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` memory must be zeroed. So what happens usually is that a kernel will map a page frame with only zeroes in there - and only when a write hits the page, a read-write mapped zero page is mapped in place.

However, this is the reason why the kernel cannot reuse the originally mapped page right away - it does not know that only the first byte of the page is dirty - instead, it must zero all 4 kiB bytes on that page before it can be given back to the process in a new anonymous mapping. Hence in both examples there are at least 1024 page faults occurring.

If the memory would not need to be zeroed, Linux for example has an extra flag called `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` that tells kernel that the pages need not be zeroed, but it is only available in embedded devices:

> **`MAP_UNINITIALIZED` (since Linux 2.6.33)**
>
> Don't clear anonymous pages.  This flag is intended  to  improve
>                 performance  on  embedded devices.  This flag is honored only if
>                 the kernel was configured with the
>       `CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED`
>     option.  Because of the security implications, that option
>                 is normally enabled only  on  embedded  devices  (i.e.,  devices
>                 where one has complete control of the contents of user memory).

I guess the reason for its non-availability in generic Linux kernels is because the kernel does not keep track of the process that previously had mapped the page frame, hence the page could leak information from a sensitive process.

---

`bzero`ing the page yourself would not affect performance - the kernel would not know that it was zeroed because there is no architecture that would support it in hardware - and then it is cheaper to **write** zeroes over the page than to **check** if the page is full of all zeroes **and** then in 99.9999999 % cases to write zeroes over it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for this. Would this trait carry over to freebsd systems such as Mac? Additionally, if I bzero this region myself again then would that result in the kernel having fewer page reclaims?

Comment: @GladwinMohlamonyane mostly... It comes from the POSIX semantics and from what the hardware is capable of. Of course other OSes can add a flag similar to `MAP_UNINITIALIZED`. It seems that OSX does not have any such flag.